# Bash Extract first number of a three digit version

Tags: awk, sed

I would like to extract number `10` from `10.3.0` for `Makefile` to add specific `CFLAGS`
Below code is printing only `1030`

```
echo "gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.3.0"|sed -r 's/.* ([0-9])/\1/g' | sed -r 's/\.//g'
1030
```

How to get the `10`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple awk:

```sh
echo "gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.3.0" | awk '{print int($NF)}'
10
```

Or if you must use `sed` only then:

```sh
echo "gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.3.0" |
sed -E 's/.* ([0-9]+).*/\1/'

10
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a tiny tweak to your own solution would do:

```
echo "gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.3.0"|sed -r 's/.* ([0-9])/\1/g' | sed -r 's/\..*//g'
10
```

Actually the second `sed` is not needed here:

```
echo "gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.3.0"|sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+).*/\1/g'
10
```

What happened is that you replaced things before `10` but not after it, which can be easily fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This solution using the `awk` functions `match()` and `substr()`:

```
echo 'gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.3.0' | awk 'match($0, /[[:digit:]]+\./) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}'
10
```

Answer (score 2):

You code using sed gives 1030 as a result because `s/.* ([0-9])/\1/g` will leave 10.3.0 and then `s/\.//g` will remove all the dots leaving 1030.

---

You could match the format `^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$`  of the last field `$NF`, and if it matches split on a dot and print the first part.

```
echo "gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.3.0" | awk 'match($NF, /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/) {
    split($NF,a,"."); print a[1]
}
'
```

Output

```
10
```

Answer (score 2):

With shown samples, you could try following. Simple explanation would be, make `.` and `)`  as field separators and print 3rd field if NF is greater than 2 for that line, to get required output as per shown samples.

```
echo "gcc.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 10" | 
awk -F'\\.|\\) ' 'NF>=2{print $3}'
```